# Get All Node Related with Parent in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table `Acc_Region`.

[image]

I need to select all nodes related with the Parent -Delta Sector-
when I use query as

```
select  Name from Acc_Region where ID = 1
```

get all cites

```
Cairo
Faysl City
Helwan City
Giza
Aiat
Saf
```

I try to use:

```
WITH RECURSIVE Region (ID, name, Parent_ID) AS
(
    SELECT ID, 
           name, 
           Parent_ID
    FROM ACC_REGION 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Acc.ID, 
           Acc.name,
           Acc.Parent_ID
    FROM ACC_REGION Acc
      JOIN Region Reg ON Acc.userid = Reg.managerid
)
SELECT *FROM ACC_REGION
```

But there are problem with `RECURSIVE`.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: So the problem you are facing is efficiency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the recursive CTE should be constructed:

```
WITH RECURSIVE_Region(ID, NAME, PARENT_ID) AS
(
   -- Anchor member: get root node
   SELECT ID, NAME, PARENT_ID
   FROM Acc_Region
   WHERE ID = 1

   UNION ALL 

   -- Recursive member: get nodes of next level   
   SELECT t1.ID, t1.NAME, t1.PARENT_ID
   FROM Acc_Region AS t1
   JOIN RECURSIVE_Region AS t2 ON t1.PARENT_ID = t2.ID
)
SELECT *
FROM RECURSIVE_Region
```

Comment: Excellent Done (Y) .